# Spaces are not respected CFBundleName or CFBundleDisplayName

Tags: ios

I am wondering how **Google Calendar** is able to maintain a space in it's display name on iOS. While my app cannot.

The issue I am about to describe below **only occurs if the app is archived and uploaded to testflight and installed on a physical device via the Testflight app**

I am trying to call my app `Toronto Ponic` with a single white space character.

Here is what I've tried so far:

1. Product name is "Toronto Ponic" i.e **CFBundleName**
2. Bundle display name is "Toronto Ponic" **CFBundleDisplayName**
3. I've tried to add `Toronto&#x2007;Ponic` for both **CFBundleName** and **CFBundleDisplayName**
4. I've tried to add `Toronto&nbsp;Ponic` for both **CFBundleName** and **CFBundleDisplayName**
5. I've tried to build my app in UIKit with Legacy build system + steps 1, 2, 3 & 4 mentioned above.

Nothing works. This issue occurs on every version of iOS 14+ and every recent version of Xcode 13.2.1 -> 13.3.1

The documentation says 30 characters max. It says nothing about stripping spaces from names with > 12 characters.

Any ideas?

Comment: Weird, I was able to name my app "Toronto Ponic" just fine on iOS 15.4: https://imgur.com/a/qiNLTMb. I just filled out the Display Name field in my the General tab of my app's target.

Comment: Did you upload the app to Testflight and install it via the Testflight app? Sorry editing my post to mention that. It works fine when the app is attached to the debugger or when running in the emulator.

Comment: I ended up filing a TSI with Apple Technical Support to see what's going on. Issue occurs on every version of iOS 14+ and every recent version of Xcode 13.2.1 -> 13.3.1.

Comment: Oh, I just installed it using the simulator.